# How Upgrade A Project From .Net 2.0 To .Net 4.0 Using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web, .net-2.0, upgrade

i am a c# web developer and vb.net project is not familiar for me.
i have a project in .net 2.0 that i want to upgrade it to .net 4.0 with using visual studio 2010.
when i open that project with visual studio 2010 every thing is normal and it seems it is working in .net 2.0.
i created a new project with visual studio and added all .net 2.0 project files to the new project.
but after that i had many errors like below :

`'List' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection`

what did i do wrong and how can i upgrade that project?
also where can i find the project's .Net framework ver for VB language (in c# we can change it by right clicking on project and properties, but here there is no such a properties)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have "Visual Studio Conversion Wizard"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer -> where is that wizard.  when i open that project no wizard comes up!

Comment: Right-click on the project in your Solution Explorer, and click "Properties".
Switch to the "Compile" tab.
Click the "Advanced Compile Options..." button.
Change the Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4."